# The cycle toon render is not working properly

Tags: shaders

I made it into a cycle toon render, but it's no different from normal diffuse render.
I hope toon shader looks like a picture of a monkey.
I know how to feel toon shader with eevee.
There's a toon node in the cycle, so I want to make it simple.

[image: toon shader cycle][image: Toonshader I want.]

Comment: Likely, the toon shader just aliases diffuse in cycles. I recommend you use an emission shader instead, but use Ray Info to keep it from actually illuminating anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Set the angle to zero in the sun of light.
It also zeroes in the bounce of light.
Then you become a true toon shader.